# How to compute $\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)$?

Tags: gamma-function

I can compute the gamma function when it is an integer multiple of $\frac{1}{2}$ or when it is a whole number. However, in this case $\frac{3}{4}$ is neither. How do I go about computing this?

---

I know the following:

$$\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$$

$$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$$

$$\Gamma(n+1)=n\Gamma(n)$$

Comment: Have you seen this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4515775/what-is-gamma1-4-im-trying-to-figure-out-how-you-would-go-about-solving-i

Comment: If you know $\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)$, you can use the [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula#Known_formulae). Its value is listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function) as well as in the linked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more context probably the best one can do is re-express it in terms of $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)$ using [Euler's reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula):

$$\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right) \Gamma\left(1 - \frac{3}{4}\right) = \pi \csc \pi \left(\frac34\right),$$
which yields
$$\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right) = \frac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)} = 1.22541\ldots .$$

There's no known expression for $\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)$ in terms of more elementary functions and more familiar constants, so per the above equation the same must be true for $\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)$. As far as I know the same is true for $\Gamma(q)$ for every rational $q$ that is not a half-integer.

Incidentally, evaluating the approximation
$$\Gamma(z) \approx \sqrt{2 \pi} z^{z - \frac{1}{2}} e^{-z} \left(1 + \frac{1}{12 z}\right),$$
which is essentially Stirling's approximation, at $z = \frac{3}{4}$ gives
$$\Gamma\left(\frac34\right) \approx \frac{2^{1/2}3^{1/4} 4^{3/4} 5 \pi^{1/2}}{18e^{3 / 4}} = 1.22431\ldots,$$ which carries a relative error of less than $10^{-3}$.

Comment: For numerical computation: $\Gamma(\frac{1}{4}) = \sqrt{4*\sqrt{\pi}*K(\frac{1}{2})}$, with $K(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{\pi}{2 \mathrm{agm}(1, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})} \approx 1.85407$. $K$ is the complete [elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) of the first kind and $\mathrm{agm}$ is the 
[arithmetic–geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean).